# Regex for grabbing payload from javascript NDEF tag

Tags: regex

I have a string that is generated from a NFC NDEF payload, below:

String:

**enMAC_98:D3:36:00:A2:90**

from this:

**`var MACdevicex = String(finalNdef.match(/MAC_(.*)/));`**

I want to grab all the text after the MAC_ part of the string. But I am getting the string below instead. I need the text after the comma from the text generated below by my match() above. I dont want to have to do another match to divide the comma section, hopefully can do it all in one match()

**Getting wrong text:**

MAC_98:D3:36:00:A2:90,98:D3:36:00:A2:90

Comment: That is 1st captured group so use: `var MACdevicex = finalNdef.match(/MAC_(.*)/)[1];`

Comment: Just `var MACdevicex = finalNdef.match(/MAC_(.*)/)[1];` is enough. Also, see [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nxda7b0t/1/).

Comment: Tried this, outputs just text "MAC: A"

Comment: You have not tried *that* - see https://jsfiddle.net/nxda7b0t/1/

Comment: Aha, anubhava has modified his first comment to be identical with mine now. :) @condo1234, just get the captured value from the string, not the whole match. With `String#match` and a non-global regex, you get an array containing [0] the whole match and [1] the captured value 1, [n] captured value n. The best way to use it is check if there is a match at all, and only then access the 2nd element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the captured value from the string, not the whole match.

With [**`String#match`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and a regex without a global modifier `g`, you get an array containing `[0]` the whole match and `[1]` the captured value `1` ... `[n]` captured value `n`.

> **Return value**
>
> An [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) containing the entire match result and any parentheses-captured matched results; [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) if there were no matches.

The best way to use it is check if there is a match at all first, and only then access the 2nd element.

```js
var MACdevicex = (m = "enMAC_98:D3:36:00:A2:90".match(/MAC_(.*)/)) ? m[1] : "";
console.log(MACdevicex);
```

Here, we assign the match result to `m`, and if there was a match, `m[1]` (the Group 1 capture value) is returned, else, `""` an empty string is returned.